# Serving static html secured by permissions in Plone

Tags: plone, zcml

I'd like to use something like the ZCML snippet below in my ZCML file to serve static HTML files from a directory. The files must be secured by a permission such as "cmf.ManagePortal", "zope.ManageContent" or similar.

```
<browser:resourceDirectory
directory="resource"
name="myresource"
permission="zope.ManageContent" />
```

Currently the plain html files are parsed as if they were zope page templates which is not what I want. According to http://bluebream.zope.org/doc/1.0/manual/browserresource.html#directory-resource .html, .pt and .zpt extensions are parsed as page templates.

I just want to serve the html as is.

I know about `<plone:static ...>` which is available with plone.resource but it doesn't support setting permissions which is something I'd like to have for my usecase.

I'm looking for guidance with one of the following:

a) A way to "deregister .html extensions from being parsed as page
    templates when in a resource directory.

b) A way to apply permissions to a static directory declared using
    `<plone:static ...>`

The following works when added to my ZCML but doesn't support setting a permission:

```
<include package="plone.resource" />
    <plone:static
      type="theme"
      name="build"
      directory="_build/html"
  />
```

Comment: Probably the only way is to serve them as page templates. What is your problem about this (apart CPU time wasting)?

Comment: @keul, it can work however the html that Sphinx is spitting out is apparently not well formed enough for the parser. As a result I keep getting errors. I was really hoping to avoid having to do too much tinkering. It seems I either need to fix Sphinx or tinker with Zope.

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine a monkey-patch to pop an entry from std lib's mimetypes.types_map dictionary. Maybe you'll want to pop key '.htm' and then reconfigure your Sphinx extension output so you can keep '.html' intact.

You can code that directly on your package's **init**.py or register it in the ZCA with collective.monkeypatcher.